# Texture Synthesis as a plugin for Blender

Tags: add-on

I Googled but there doesn't seem to be an add-on or tool for Blender that can synthesize textures from a small sample texture. From my experience with Blender, sourcing tileable or high-quality textures usually requires a good bit of effort.
This [paper](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/papers/efros-siggraph01.pdf) shows a technique which could be adapted as a plugin for Blender and I was wondering if it or any variation of it already exists because I want to implement it as an add-on for Blender.